# How are you supposed to learn the order of the buttons in the pirates' tower?

Tags: lufia-and-the-fortress-of-doom

I'm playing through Lufia and the Fortress of Doom for the first time, almost three decades late, and I've come to something that has me stuck.

In the pirates' tower, when you need to rescue Professor Shaia, there's a door that you have to enter a code to open. The only hints I've gotten are that the top left button is probably first, and that you don't press all four buttons. This is clearly not enough information to determine the order of the buttons, and I don't feel like trying every possible combination. But I've scoured the whole tower, and haven't found any other hints. I don't want to just be told what the answer is, so:

How are players supposed to figure out the order of the buttons in this tower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, unfortunately, after much searching and talking to people who know the game well, it would seem the intent is for the player to figure it out by trial and error.

It also turns out that the hint that says you don't press all the buttons is a lie. Whether intentional or a poor translation, I'm not sure, but you do press all four buttons.

Comment: To be fair, if the clue that the top left button is first is correct and each button is only used once, then there are only 9 combinations to try with four total buttons. That's not a lot of combinations.

Comment: @Kadima Yes, but I tried all the combinations with fewer than four buttons first, as I didn't think that hint was a lie.